# Operand type clash: xml is incompatible with text

Tags: exception, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, receive-location

I am passing a CSV file to the receive location of my orchestration and I had this error

> Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an
>   instance of service
>   'A4SADAD.Biller.ANB.FileExtraction.AccountsExtractionProcessor(ec7a8243-253d-8380-daa9-236e4c9873f8)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated.  If resumed the instance will continue from its
>   last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: 39ad30d2-346e-494c-b283-86be5f58bd77 Shape name: Call
>   StoreBillsInfo ShapeId: 1f495667-8e5f-490a-9f0e-7b7e98147412 Exception
>   thrown from: segment 2, progress 12 Inner exception: Operand type
>   clash: xml is incompatible with text
>            Exception type: DalException Source: A4SADAD.Biller.ANB.Common Target Site: Void
>   Handle(A4SADAD.Biller.ANB.Common.Exceptions.ExceptionPolicies)

The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occurred

> at
>   A4SADAD.Biller.ANB.Common.Exceptions.BaseException.Handle(ExceptionPolicies
>   policy)    at A4SADAD.Biller.ANB.Common.Except

any ideas why I'm having this error ??

Comment: Could you please specify the pipeline configuration of the physical port, whether you have defined a general-purpose or a specific flat file disassembly pipeline, and your flat file schema?

Comment: Solved, it was the type of the parameter in the stored procedure which was declared as text not xml.